# como saber si un dispositivo posee camara con flash?

Tags: java, android

Hola estoy programando en android studio y necesito saber como hago para detectar si un dispositivo android tiene camara con flash para luego lanzar un Toast informando si tiene o no camara con flash.

Comment: Mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547524/4092887). Si esa respuesta te ha ayudado, recuerda votar a favor y podrías publicar tu propia respuesta aquí. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave la información que agregas es buena pero la clase Camara es obsoleta desde la API level 21. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo mediante:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Lo que realizar es revisar en las caracteristicas del sistema si la camara soporta el flash [CAMERA_FLASH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)

---

Este sería el `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)?"Camara tiene Flash":"Camara no tiene flash",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para revisar disponibilidad del flash en un dispositivo:

Usar:

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Retorna true si el flash esta disponible, false si no.

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas. Puedes comprobar si tiene flash del siguiente modo:

```
boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Si este código no te funciona, puedes probar este otro:

```
Camera camera; // Inicializas la cámara
public boolean hasFlash() {
    if (camera == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
        return false;
    }

    List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
    if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Puedes ver la fuente aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599365/4682937

Comment: La clase Camera ahora es obsoleta desde API level 21.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, recuerda que la mayoría de los dispositivos tienen mas de una camara.

Lo que se debe hacer es primero obtener una lista de las cámaras disponibles y posteriormente buscar entre ellas cual tiene flash, si alguna tiene flash entonces retornas un 'True'.

La manera correcta es hacer eso de la API Camera2 de Google.

Prueba este codigo:

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
    boolean hasFlash = false;
    //Primero obtienes el servicio de camara.
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        //Obtienes todos los ID'S de las camaras disponibles
        //Por lo regular son dos (Camara trasera, Camara frontal)
        String[] cameraIds = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
        //Buscas entre todas ellos si esque alguna tiene flash.
        for (String cameraId :
                cameraIds) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE).booleanValue())
                hasFlash = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hasFlash;
}
```